# Haskell replace space with Char

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to come up with a function that will replace all the blank spaces in a string with `"%50"` or similar and I know I'm messing up something with my types but can't seem to figure it out I have been trying the following (yes I have imported `Data.Char`)

```
newLine :: String -> String
newLine xs = if x `elem` " " then "%50"
```

I also tried the if then else statement but really didn't know what to do with the else so figured just lowercase all the letters with

```
newLine xs = [if x `elem` ' ' then '%50' else toLower x | x<-xs]
```

would like the else statement to simply do nothing but have searched and found no way of doing that so i figured if everything was lowercase it wouldn't really matter just trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simple solution

```
newLine :: String -> String
newline ""       = ""
newLine (' ':xs) = '%':'5':'0': newLine xs
newLine (x:xs)   = x: newLine xs
```

or use library function

Comment: That does look much simpler, I'm always over thinking these things the help is much appreciated, though I am getting the following error so it's half way there: "test%50spaces*** Exception: WebAdd.hs:(21,1)-(22,32): Non-exhaustive patterns in function newLine            any Ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: That's because the empty string case is missing, you need to add this line: `newline [] = []` (or equivalently: `newline "" = ""`)

Answer (score 0):

You're running into type mismatch issues. The approach you're currently using would work *if* you were replacing a `Char` with another `Char`. For example, to replace spaces with asterisks:

```
newLine xs = [if x == ' ' then '*' else toLower x | x<-xs]
```

Or if you wanted to replace both spaces and newlines with asterisks, you could use the `elem` function. But note that the `elem` function takes an array (or a String, which is the same as [Char]). In your example, you were trying to pass it a single element, `' '`. This should work:

```
newLine xs = [if x `elem` " \n" then '*' else toLower x | x<-xs]
```

However, you want to replace a `Char` with a `String` (`[Char]`). So you need a different approach. The solution suggested by viorior looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the list comprehension is almost correct. Problem is:

- "`%50`"  is not a valid character literal, so you can't have `'%50'`. If you actually mean *the three characters* `%`, `5` and `0`, it needs to be a `String` instead.
- `' '` *is* a correct character literal, but the character `x` can't be *element* of another char. You certainly mean simply `x == ' '`.

Now that would suggest the solution

```
    [if x == ' ' then "%50" else toLower x | x<-xs]
```

but this doesn't quite work because you're mixing strings (`"%50"`) and single-characters in the same list. That can easily be fixed though, by "promoting" `x` to a single-char *string*:

```
    [if x == ' ' then "%50" else [toLower x] | x<-xs]
```

The result has then type `[String]`, which can be "flattened" to a single string with the prelude `concat` function.

```
     concat [if x == ' ' then "%50" else [toLower x] | x<-xs]
```

An alternative way of writing this is

```
     concatMap (\x -> if x == ' ' then "%50" else [toLower x]) xs
```

or – exactly the same with [more general infix operators](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad)

```
     xs >>= \x -> if x == ' ' then "%50" else [toLower x]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this *also* convert the string to lowercase?

Comment: Yes, of course. I understood the OP also wanted this, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

To replace characters with possibly longer strings, one can follow this approach:

```
-- replace single characters
replace :: Char -> String
replace ' ' = "%50"
replace '+' = "Hello" 
replace c | isAlpha c = someStringFunctionOf c
replace _   = "DEFAULT"

-- extend to strings
replaceString :: String -> String
replaceString s = concat (map replace s)
```

The last line can also be written as

```
replaceString s = concatMap replace s
```

or even

```
 replaceString s = s >>= replace
```

or even

```
 replaceString = (>>= replace)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List
newLine :: String -> String
newLine  = intercalate "%50" . words
```